# Keeping ResultSet of a JDBC query in a class attribute vs. simply returning it

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working on a connection manager class at the moment which will be called multiple times. Its purpose is to establish a connection and return results as a result set, but i have some questions about it.

Is it faster to create a result set variable in the function or change the result set field of the object and than return it?

Here are two examples

Option 1:

```java
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*********";
    private static String username = "root";
    private static String password = "admin123";

    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {
        ResultSet results = null;
        try {
            Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.username, this.password);
            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
            results = statement.executeQuery(query);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return results;
    }

}
```

option 2:

```java
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*********";
    private static String username = "root";
    private static String password = "admin123";
    private ResultSet results = null;


    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {
        try {
            Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.username, this.password);
            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
            this.results = statement.executeQuery(query);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this.results;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are missing a *lot* of details here. How will it be used? Will there be multiple concurrent users? What does "creating variables on the go" mean? What does it connect to? Can you show code examples of those two options you are considering?

Comment: I edited the post for the option i am looking for. I am new to programming in general so if their are anytips about how to open a database more effeciently, safely, you name it. It would be much appriciated

Comment: Given this leaks the connection and the statement, this is bad code overall. Do not do this (either solution!). Your connection manager doesn't really serve a good purpose and tries to wrap JDBC in suboptimal way. You'd be better off using JDBC directly, maybe using an appropriate `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation (use an existing one, don't write one!) for creating the `Connection`.

Comment: Why would you want to keep stale data hanging around instead of reading fresh data as and when required?

Comment: Tip: Learn about (a) [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close your JDBC resource objects, and (b) Find a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) implementation for your particular database to hold your database connection info. Also, [RowSets](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jcrowset.htm) may be of interest to you. In particular, `CachedRowSet`. And learn about [records](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

Answer (score 1):

As written, Option 1 is not very different from Option 2: in Option 2, the `ResultSet` attribute is `private` (as mutable class attributes should generally be), and therefore not accessible to the outside world (= code outside of this class). Since Option 2 has no advantages over Option 2 (local variables are essentially free, but instance attributes should be chosen more wisely), **you should go with Option 1**. But there are other problems:

- you are not closing all those connections that you are opening. This may result in resource exhaustion and your app crashing. However, this does not have an easy fix, because you should not close the connection until the `ResultSet` has been processed, or it may be impossible to process it later.
- in Option 2, if you call `executeQuery` from 2 threads at approximately the same time, it is possible that both calls will return the 2nd `ResultSet`. So **Option 2 is dangerous** in the presence of concurrency.

I would propose the following fixes:

- store a `private Connection connection;` as a class attribute. This will give you much better performance, as establishing connections to a DB is costly, and reestablishing connections *once per query* and never closing them has bad consequences. Establish the connection in the constructor.
- have a `public void close()` method, which simply does `connection.close()`. This fixes the "not closing connections" problem. Call this only when you are sure that no new queries will be made, for instance when the application is shutting down.
- have `executeQuery` return the corresponding `resultSet` by querying the previously-opened connection, instead of connecting anew in each and every call. Of course, we are going with Option 1: we return a fresh `ResultSet` for each new query.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about performance, it's about design. And primary difference between two options is about having a *state* or not. Shared field will very likely bring problems with multithreading and mixed usage scenarios, whereas local variable is closer to "functional" aproach keeping the `ResultSet` isolated in caller's context.

And IMHO, performance in this case should only be considered after utility and usability.

Comment: I searched up mutithreading after you comment and functionally it would be much better to keep it as a local variable. even though it wil not be done in this app i am making it wil be part of making it more maintanable and expandable.